# removing duplicates from xml file use xslt

Tags: xml, replace, xslt-1.0, mbeans

Here is an example where i have two `<mbean>` sections with same name, but the properties in these sections are diffrent, I would like to merge these two `<mbean>` sections and duplicate propeties has to replace with the latest one that is added to bottom of `<mbean>` section.

```
        <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">                   
                <jndi:binding
                    name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        old-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                      <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">                   
                <jndi:binding
                    name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        new-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                      <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcFileNet">
                      <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcFileNet@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
```

Expected output is:

```
                <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
        name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">                   
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                      <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding
                    name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        new-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcFileNet">
                      <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcFileNet@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings> 
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** for removing duplicates

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="mbeanName" match="//mbean/@name" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mbean[not(generate-id(@name) = generate-id(key('mbeanName', @name)[1]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        old-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        new-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcFileNet">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcFileNet@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</root>
```

### OUTPUT:

```
<root>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="abc.myconfig.jndi:name=myconfigAppPartitionJNDI">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        old-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myabcdefService/myabcdefServiceUrl">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                            @myabcdefService.myabcdefServiceUrl@
                      </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</root>
```

### UPDATED XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="mbeanName" match="//mbean/@name" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="mbeanCount" match="//mbean[generate-id(@name) = generate-id(key('mbeanName', @name)[1])]" use="count(.)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mbean[count(. | key('mbeanCount', /mbean/@name))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Charan, the expected output is something diffrent than your output: `<jndi:binding name="myabc/myconfig/myservice/myabcservice">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        new-value
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>`

Comment: When you gather the nodes mbean by name, wouldn't the muenchian method just give you the first node of the ones with the same name?  What if you also indexed the jndi:value nodes and used the same technique to output them underneath mbean?

Comment: @Jeremy is possible to put some example?

Comment: The comment space doesn't have enough characters to fit an explanation of what I was thinking, so I will put it as an answer, but please bear in mind that this is untested and just a technique that occurred to me.  You would have to play with it to get it working properly.

Comment: @phani: Updated the answer with new XSLT. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @SivaCharan, that is awesome.  I can see in the template match at the end, you're basically removing any node where the call to count() doesn't return 0, is that correct?  Could you explain how the mbeanCount key works?  I'm not sure I understand it, because in the key declaration it looks like it returns a count, but in the xpath predicate in the template match attribute, it looks like it's returning a nodeset.

Answer (score 0):

The mbean template in Siva Charan's answer eliminates mbean elements where the @name is duplicated, so that part you want to keep.

I was thinking that maybe you could add a template matching mbean that gathered up all the attribute nodes where the parent node has the same name.  So underneath the mbean template, you would be selecting an xpath something like this `../mbean/attribute[../@name = current()/@name]` and let's say you set that to a variable `$attributes`.  Then you hard code `<attributes>` and `<jndi:bindings>`, and then output all `$attributes/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding` such that `jndi:value` is unique.  So for that, I guess you'd set a key matching jndi:value, and then make an xpath something like `jndi:binding[generate-id(jndi:value) = generate-id(key('jndivals', jndi:value)[1])]`

Sorry this is so sketchy, but like I said, these are just thoughts that I haven't tested.  I hope that helps at least a little bit, and that I'm not going in completely the wrong direction.

Comment: Updated my answer with new XSLT. Check it out.

Comment: @Jeremy, I like the idea. Due to time constraint, for now I choose to go with charan solution.